# mysql: find newest non null values

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table with 100 fields. Each row is timestamped. I want to find the latest non null value for all columns. I'm using MySql 5.6 InnoDB

e.g.

```
create table tester(
pub_id int,
pub_name varchar(20),
pub_city varchar(20),
country varchar(20),
no_of_branch varchar(20),
estd datetime
);


insert into tester (pub_id, pub_name, pub_city, country, estd)
values 
(1,  'a', 'xyz', 'abcity' , 'a', '1970-01-01 00:00:01'),
(2,  'a', 'xyz', ''       , 'a', '1971-01-01 00:00:01'),
(3,  'a', 'xyz', 'abcity1', 'b', '1972-01-01 00:00:01'),
(4,  'a', 'xyz', ''       , 'a', '1973-01-01 00:00:01'),
(5,  'a', 'xyz', 'abcity2', '' , '1974-01-01 00:00:01'),
(6,  'b', 'lmn', 'abcity' , 'a', '1974-01-01 00:00:01'),
(7,  'b', 'xyz', ''       , 'a', '1975-01-01 00:00:01'),
(8,  'b', 'sdf', 'abcity1', 'b', '1976-01-01 00:00:01'),
(9,  'b', ''   , ''       , 'a', '1977-01-01 00:00:01'),
(10, 'b', ''   , 'abcity2', '' , '1978-01-01 00:00:01');
```

I want to query that would give me:

```
'a', 'xyz', 'abcity2', 'a'
'b', 'sdf', 'abcity2', 'b'
```

I don't want to use a query where i find empty values for each column of the table individually and then take a join as this would be a very cumbersome task given that my actual table has 100 columns.

I have searched for a solution for the past of couple of ours and found nothing. ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly your question ? you search a "tricky" way to do it to avoid building a query with 100 conditions ?

Comment: yes. I'm sure there is a better way to do this search in SQL.

Comment: Your algorithm is unclear. How do you reach this expected result? It seems you're grouping by pub_name.

Comment: In Oracle I'd use LAG analytical function with ignoring NULLS option. As I know in MySQL there is a way to emulate such functions.

Comment: @Sebas You're right I'm grouping on pub_name.

Comment: Hmm... with mysql, it's going to be tough to be elegant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the "tricky" way you are looking for.

First create a twin table (`tester2`) to receive the aggregated data.  This new table must have a primary key on `pub_name` and all the columns you want to aggregate.  Then do an `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This query will basically rebuild the `tester` table but without duplicate and with aggregated data.  In fact something like this :

```
insert into tester2 (pub_name, pub_city, country, no_of_branch)
  select pub_name, pub_city, country, no_of_branch FROM tester order by estd desc
on duplicate key 
update
   pub_city = coalesce(tester2.pub_city,tester.pub_city), 
   country = coalesce(tester2.country,tester.country), 
   no_of_branch = coalesce(tester2.no_of_branch,tester.no_of_branch)
```

The content of `tester2` will be :

```
PUB_NAME   PUB_CITY   COUNTRY   NO_OF_BRANCH
a          xyz        abcity2   a
b          sdf        abcity2   a
```

Have a look the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oFbcMNJTNUr3c5EuC55ow5/0).

**Note :** I assume you mean real `NULL` values and not empty string like the sample you provided.

Comment: thanks. This looks like its perfect in the fiddle. I'm going to try it on my dataset and come back and accept this as the answer. I tried using an if condition just to check for null and empty string but doesn't seem to work. Which in all probability implies I'm doing something wrong, but that's more of a curiosity. Thanks again

Comment: Should've used case condition. [Here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/924834/1) that works with nulls and empty string